# Pop-Up Window Under Current Window - Chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to open a popup window UNDER the current browser window to permit a behind-the-scenes maintenance task (delete thread button press).

The delete thread function is working as needed, except I cannot seem to get the popup to appear under the main browser window.  Trying "popup.blur();" without success on Chrome v54.  Any suggestions?

```
(function() { 
    'use strict'; 
    $("a.PreviewTooltip").each(function() { 
       $(this).after("&nbsp;<img data-link='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' title='Ignore this thread' class='inlineimg runIgnore' src='data:image/gif;base64,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%3D%3D' alt='Ignore this thread' border='1'></i> ");
    }); 
    $(".runIgnore").click(function() { 
    var oldHref = $(this).data('link'); 
    var newHref = oldHref; 
    var suffixToIgnore = "/unread"; 
    if (newHref.endsWith(suffixToIgnore)) 
    { 
        newHref = newHref.substring(0, newHref.length - suffixToIgnore.length + 1); 
    } 
        newHref = newHref + "ignore-confirm"; 
        var popup = window.open(newHref, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=100, top=500, width=500, height=500, visible=false', '');
        $(popup).load(function() { 
            var ignoreForumSubmitButton = popup.$("input[value='Ignore Thread']"); 
            var ignoreForumForm = ignoreForumSubmitButton.closest("form"); 
            ignoreForumSubmitButton.click(); 
            popup.parent.focus(); 
            popup.blur(); 
            $(popup).unload(function() {} ); 
            setTimeout(function() { popup.close(); }, 100); 
            setTimeout(function() { parent.location.reload(true); }, 100); 
        }); 
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: Modern browsers will generally not allow you control over that sort of thing.

Comment: Do it within a hidden ifame?

Comment: I'd recommend using AJAX for this, especially as you're already using jQuery.  It would be very trivial to do this.

Comment: Don't use a popup as a worker. If the user isn't going to interact with the popup, use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) instead. They have no DOM access and are run on a separate thread for each worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully opened popup in a hidden iFrame:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var iframe;
    function loadIntoFrame(url, callback)
    {
        iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
        iframe.width = 1;
        iframe.height = 1;
        iframe.id = "childframe";
        iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
        iframe.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }

    function submitIgnoreForm()
    {
        var ignoreForumSubmitButton = $("#childframe").contents().find("input[value='Ignore Thread']");
        var ignoreForumForm = ignoreForumSubmitButton.closest("form");
        ignoreForumSubmitButton.click();

        setTimeout( function() { iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe); }, 200);
        setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 100 );
    }

    $("a.PreviewTooltip").each(function() {
       $(this).after("&nbsp;<img data-link='" + $(this).attr('href') + "' title='Ignore this thread' class='inlineimg runIgnore' src='data:image/gif;base64,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%3D%3D' alt='Ignore this thread' border='1'></i>");
    });

    $(".runIgnore").click(function() {
        var oldHref = $(this).data('link');
        var newHref = oldHref;
        var suffixToIgnore = "/unread";
        if (newHref.endsWith(suffixToIgnore))
        {
            newHref = newHref.substring(0, newHref.length - suffixToIgnore.length + 1);
        }
        newHref = newHref + "ignore-confirm";
        loadIntoFrame(newHref, submitIgnoreForm);

    });
})();
```